# Use NULL foreign key or point to a reserved record?

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database containing messages and messengers.

```
create table Message(
    MessageID int,
    MessengerID int,
    Content nvarchar(max)
)
create table Messenger(
    MessengerID int,
    MessengerName nvarchar(100)
)
```

Sometimes the messenger in unknown. Would you use a NULL value in that case, or a reserved record for unknown messengers in the Messenger table? I'd love to see a short explanation why one solution is better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. I would use another table for the messenger info:

```
CREATE TABLE MessageMessenger(
    MessageID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Message (MessageID),
    MessengerID int NOT NULL REFERENCES Messenger (MessengerID));
```

(I note in passing that ALL your columns are nullable and your tables don't have keys. I would fix that first!)

NULL in SQL does not accurately represent the semantics of something being "unknown". Using it that way frequently leads to contradictions and incorrect results and it isn't necessary if you design tables that accurately model the situation that the database is supposed to represent.

Another reason not to use nullable foreign keys is that different DBMSs disagree on how they work and users probably won't understand them or use them correctly.

Comment: I would argue the very concept of NULL being Unknown is the standard. See [Null Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx).

Comment: But when I do a join query using an association table (MessageMessenger), don't I still get NULLs in the result set on all Message rows without a known Messenger?

Comment: Batibix: What result do you *want* to get? If an inner join then you won't get nulls (which is the same result you would get from an inner join on a null foreign key). Most of the time when a database designer adds a null into the database then the person who designs screens and reports on top of that database is forced to eliminate them or hide the nulls. By not putting nulls in you ensure maximum flexibility as well as correctness. The developer / end user can decide what results he wants from his queries without having to worry unduly about whether nulls will cause any incorrect results.

Comment: The result I want, is that all messages are listed whether the messenger is known or not. Thus, inner joins won't be any good in this case. The end user should either see the messenger name or "Unknown messenger" in listings, whichever the case may be. So, the developer (me) will get nulls in the result set whether an association table is used or not. Or is there a way around this, that I've missed?

Comment: Batibix - There is a way around it. As you've just said, you *don't* want nulls, you want a specific message displayed in a list. So you can outer join the MessageMessenger table with the other tables and use COALESCE() to return that message where the MessengerId is not in the table.

Answer (score 4):

I would use NULL.

1. This is exactly what NULL exists for. To say "I've no idea what it is."
2. Having a reserved record in a table is always a pain. You now have to say to your users, hey, you can add more messengers if you wish, and you can delete them, and you can even amend, but don't delete this line, and that line, too. This causes unnecessary complications.

Comment: To say nothingh of all the queries that have to avoid including the reference to the reserved record.

Comment: Yes, I suspected a thousand pains with a reserved record. What I'd want is some sort of database equivalent to the null object pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: The database equivalent of a null object would be an empty set or empty string for example, not a null. Don't get confused by the confusing multiple meanings of the word "null". Null in SQL is sui generis. It is a very different thing from the "null set" in mathematics or a "null object" in OOP.